# Reading archive using 7-zip

Tags: c#, .net, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to find a way to read the contents/ file names of a zipped file, unzip the files and then create a text file with a list of all the files unzipped.

Most of that isn't a problem but reading and using the files in an archive is proving to be harder than it should be.

My current code is ...

```
var options = new Options();
            ICommandLineParser parser = new CommandLineParser();

            string strInput = "", strOutput = "", strExtract = "", strPassword = "";

            Console.WriteLine("parsing..");

            if (parser.ParseArguments(args, options))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("checking...");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.InputFile))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("input is empty");
                    Console.WriteLine(options.GetUsage()); 
                }

                strInput = options.InputFile;
                strOutput = options.OutputFile;
                strExtract = options.ExtractFormat;
                strPassword = options.Password;

                ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
                p.FileName = "7za.exe";

                Console.WriteLine("x " + "-" + strExtract + " -p" + strPassword + " " + strInput + " -o" + strOutput);
                p.Arguments = "x " + "-" + strExtract + " -p" + strPassword + " " + strInput + " -o" + strOutput;
                p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                Process x = Process.Start(p);
                x.WaitForExit();
```

I have found a few resources to help but none have worked so far. 
Resources found: 
http://pastebin.com/eTRE4TPP (I dont understand how they are using an undeclared variable, "l", but even changing that to "p" it doesnt work. 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples (Command l looks like it could be used but I dont see how I can take the file names and store them)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why use an external process? Why not use SharpZip or DotNetZip?

Comment: Well I'm using 7-zip command line anyway (Due to specification and requirements) so I figured it must have a way to get and manipulate the files in an archive. If not I might have to use something else as well as 7-Zip.

Answer (score -1):

What is it specifically that required you to use 7Zip? [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) may be able to do what you need.